# Intermingling of Play application global settings

Tags: java, scala, maven, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have two Play 2.2.1 applications, X and Y. Both of these applications have a Global object in the default package that extends GlobalSettings and overrides onStart. Application X is published in a maven repo and application Y has X as a dependency. When attempting to run application Y, I keep getting strange exceptions during onStart. These exceptions are getting thrown by code in application X's onStart function. I did not get any compile-time errors or warnings.

Is this expected? Is this a Play specific issue or would this happen any time names in the default package conflict like this? How can I prevent the GlobalSettings of the apps from mixing together?

I had originally put the common code into its own project that the two Play app's shared as a dependency. This was annoying to maintain and all of the shared code really belonged to app X, so I reorganized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you're seeing would stem from the fact that you have multiple `Global` objects in your classloader, and which one is loaded is undefined.  The classloader is like a filesystem, you can only have one file with a given name in a given directory.  If you have two libraries on your classpath that define a file with the same name in the same directory, they don't combine, rather one overrides the other, and which one gets used depends on classloader implementations - in Play we specifically don't define the ordering.

The `Global` object must *only* be defined by end applications.  Any project that is intended to be consumed as a dependency must not define a `Global` object.  It should rather define the behaviour somewhere that can be consumed by a `Global` object.  If it wants to transparently plugin behaviour on start, consider implementing the `Plugin` interface instead, as documented here:

http://developer.vz.net/2012/03/16/writing-a-play-2-0-module/

Comment: Thanks for explaining why this is happening. It makes sense to me that one would have to override the other, but I am surprised it happens silently. In my situation, both of the apps are actually end applications that communicate with one another. I wanted to reuse some model code between both apps (such as serialization/deserialization code).

Comment: Well it sounds like it's not failing that silently :)  But duplicates on the classpath does fail silently because that's the way Java's URL classloader works, two JARs with the same file won't trigger an error.  If you want to reuse the model code, pull that code out into a third project that the two applications depend on.